# Ionic v1 AngularJS $http POST request not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, angularjs-service, angularjs-http

I'm trying to send a POST request to a rest API, but I don't seem to able to do it correctly, I don't know if it's the syntax, or what it could be, I've tried many different ways but nothing seems to work. Here's is some pictures of the service being consumed by POSTMAN (everything works fine here).

1. The Headers
   [image]
2. And the body with the response[image]

But then when I try to consume the service via AngularJS, it keeps sending me erros messages, the localhost server even detects that there is a request, because I can see it on the Eclipse's console, but it doesn't run through the debugger with togglebreakpoints and it does with POSTMAN.

This is one of the many attempts to send a $http request

```
    var json = { practiceId: 1 };

    $http({
        method: "POST",
        url: "https://localhost/GetAppointmentTypes",
        data: JSON.stringify(json),
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          "AERONA-AUTH-TOKEN": $window.localStorage['token']
        }
    })
    .success(function(data) {
      $ionicPopup.alert({
            title: 'WORKING'
      });
    })
    .error(function (errResponse, status) {
      if(status == 403){
            $ionicPopup.alert({
                title: '403'
        });
      }
    });
```

But then [image]

And here is another attempt

```
  var url = 'https://localhost/GetAppointmentTypes';

  var parameter = JSON.stringify({practiceId:1});

  var headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "AERONA-AUTH-TOKEN": $window.localStorage['token']
  };


  $http.post(url, parameter, headers).then(function(response){
      $ionicPopup.alert({
          title: 'WORKING'
      });
  }, function(response){
    $ionicPopup.alert({
        title: ' NOT WORKING '
    });
  });
```

And the response [image]

Note: the $window.localStorage['token'] is working correctly. I have tried so many things I don't even know what I'm doing wrong now, might be a syntax error, but then ERROR 403 wouldn't be showing.

EDITED (ADDED)

And the Response Variable [image]

Comment: what is inside response ?

Comment: can you post API file data ? if you are using  custom API, add header `header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header( 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization, Content-Type' );` in your API file

Comment: I'm editing the question with what's in the response variable, sorry if it's confusing, I'm running the app on a emulator and I debug through alerts, maybe not the best way to do it.